# An observation of prime number, not sure if this always hold

Tags: summation, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I have little math background and I just do some random observations on prime numbers and notice that:

for $p > k$ where $p$ is a prime and $k$ is a positive integer:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} 2^{ip} = 0\pmod{2^k-1}$$

For example, pick $p = 5$ and $k = 3$:
$$\sum_{i=0}^2 2^{5i} = 2^{10}+2^5+1=1057=7\times151=(2^3-1)\cdot151 $$

pick $p = 7$ and $k = 4$:
$$\sum_{i=0}^3 2^{7i} = 2^{21}+2^{14}+2^{7}+1=2113665=15 \cdot 140911=(2^4-1) \cdot 140911 $$

pick $p = 11$ and $k = 7$:
$$\sum_{i=0}^6 2^{11i} = 2^{66}+2^{55}+2^{44}+2^{33}+2^{22}+2^{11}+1=
73823022692637345793 \\ =127\times581283643249112959=(2^7-1)\cdot581283643249112959 $$

I cannot find any similar observations related to this elsewhere, and it would be really appreciated if anyone could provide some guidance on whether this always holds. I am very curious about that.
Thank you!

Comment: This seems heavily related to Mersenne primes.

Comment: aha: I just do some manipulations, and figure out that this question can be reformalized as such: $(2^{pk}-1) = 0\ mod\ (2^p-1)(2^k-1)$

Comment: @ellocz Hint: $\;\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} 2^{ip} = 2^{kp} - 1\,$.

Comment: @dxiv You are right, I just figure it out that this problem may be reformatted a little bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any positive integers $k$ and $p$, $x^{kp}-1$ is divisible (as a polynomial) by both $x^k-1$ and $x^p-1$.  Moreover, if $k$ and $p$ are coprime the gcd of $x^p-1$ and $x^k-1$ is $x-1$.  Thus if $k$ and $p$ are coprime, $x^{kp}-1$ is divisible by 
$(x^k-1)(x^p-1)/(x-1)$.  Taking $x=2$, $2^{kp}-1$ is divisible by $(2^k-1)(2^p-1)$ in these cases.

Comment: Thank you! I also noticed that if kp+1 is prime, that number is also divisible by kp+1 (according to fermat little theorem). Am I right?